# marionettejs event bubbling from child views not firing

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I have `LayoutView`, `CollectionView` and `ItemView`. First I generate the layout and pass the `collection` to `CollectionView`to generate childView (`ItemView`). I want to trace event triggered within `ItemView` bubble up to `LayoutView`.

Here how trigger the event inside `ItemView`

```
    onRender: function() {  
        if (this.model.get('ig_id') == this.ig_id) {
            this.$el.addClass('active');                
            this.trigger("selected", this.model);
        }
    }
```

And I try to reach the triggered event `selected` within `LayoutView`

```
    initialize: function(opt) {
        this.listenTo(this.mainTab, "show", this.mainTabShown, this);
    },
    mainTabShown: function (view) {
        this.listenTo(view, "childview:selected", this.generateTabContent, this);
    }
```

But no successful until now.

Comment: Are you sure, mainTabShown function is being executed?

Comment: when I put `console.log(view)`, it work

Comment: when I put `console.log(view)`, it work. Even if I do childEvents within `CollectionView` also work

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of problem, pay attention to ItemView `onShow` method

revise the from `onRender` to `onShow`